# html5 boilerplate doesn't include reset.css?

Tags: css, reset, html5boilerplate, normalize

I am using [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and don't find any reset style. All H1 elements has 50px of margin top and bottom :S

Do i need to include something like [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) by my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default package uses normalize.css inside style.css (but obviously not all of it). If you want to reset all the styles, you have to add it on your own.

http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/css/